# Express router middleware gets called on unexpected routes

Tags: express, routes

Using express, I have multiple routes where I need some middleware. They aren't under any common `/url/path`.

[Router-level middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.router) says:

> Router-level middleware works in the same way as application-level middleware, except it is bound to an instance of express.Router()

As I read it, the implication is that the middleware applies only to the routes of the router instance. But that seems not to be the case.

In the following example, I expect "router called" to be logged only for `http://localhost:10000/router`.

But it gets logged for `http://localhost:10000/noRouter` also, which I don't understand. Why does middleware `use`d by the `router` instance get called for routes that are added to `app` directly? Is it possible to create a `Router` so that only routes bound to that `Router` get the middleware applied?

```js
const express = require('express')

const app = express()
const port = 10000

const router = express.Router();
router.use((req, _res, next) => {
    console.log("router called")
    next()
})

app.use(router)

router.get('/router', (req, res) => {
    res.send("ok")
})

app.get('/noRouter', (req, res) => {
    res.send("ok")
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

P.S.: I'm not stuck and have it working using a different approach. I just want to understand why this doesn't work...

Comment: Because that middleware's _first_, isn't limited to specific routes, and calls next - that's what's _supposed_ to happen.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Hmmm. I'm not usually thick, but I still don't understand. You've put `first` in italics but `first` only appears in [Router-level middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.router) once in an unrelated context that I do understand. I still don't see what is meant by my middleware function being "bound to an instance of express.Router()". But thanks for _trying_ to enlighten me! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A router is just inserted into a chain of request handlers and is searched/executed in order.

Because you do this:

```
app.use(router)
```

You are specifically sending ALL requests to your router.  So, all requests will wind through the various handlers in that router looking for one that matches the incoming path.  That will include your `router.use()` middleware which matches ALL paths so it will execute for every URL that gets sent to your router.  There is no logic in a router that first checks to see if some route in the router matches before it executes any middleware.  A router works just like the `app` object in this regard and executes middleware in the order it encounters them.  So, the only way your middleware doesn't get executed is if the request never gets to the router at all.

If you want middleware to only apply to routes in a router, then you have a couple choices:

Put the router on a common path prefix such as:

```
app.use("/somerouterprefix", router);
```

Then, only URLs that get routed to your router will run the middleware in the router.  This will, of course, only execute the middleware for routes that start with that prefix, but it will also execute the middleware for routes that start with the prefix, but don't even have a matching route handler in the router.  Remember, I said earlier that everything that gets sent to the router will cause your middleware to execute.

Or, secondly, put the middleware on each individual handler in your router so that it will only get executed when it matches some route on your router such as:

```
const router = express.Router();

// give the middleware a function name so you can 
//   use it in specific route definitions
function myMiddleware((req, _res, next) => {
    console.log("router called")
    next()
});

// specify the middleware in your route definition
router.get('/router', myMiddleware, (req, res) => {
    res.send("ok")
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using solution #2, since as I said "they aren't under any common /url/path". Given this explanation, I think this quote from the docs is misleading: "Router-level middleware works in the same way as application-level middleware, except it is bound to an instance of express.Router()".

Comment: @PeterV.Mørch - That specific phrase in the docs is technically correct, but does not tell the whole story.  If an incoming request is sent to a router via the middleware that you registered the router with, then `router.use()` in that router works just like `app.use()`.  The difference is if the router is registered in a way that only some requests are sent to the router (as in the first example in my answer).