# Router level middleware is getting applied to app level middlewares

Tags: node.js, express

I have two routers, `userRouter` and `conversationRouter`. I've applied the `validateToken` middleware specifically to the `conversationRouter`. However, when I call any route from either `userRouter` or `conversationRouter`, the validateToken middleware is unexpectedly invoked. This issue is resolved when I change the order of mounting the routers. Below are code examples from each file for reference:

1. `userRouter.ts`

   ```
   const userRouter = express.Router();

   userRouter.post('/login', login);
   export default userRouter;
   ```
2. `conversationRouter.ts`

   ```
   const conversationRouter = express.Router();

   conversationRouter.use(validateToken);
   conversationRouter.post('/api/conversation', postConversation);

   export default conversationRouter;
   ```
3. `app.ts`

   ```
   const app = express();
   app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '10mb' }));
   app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: '10mb' }));
   app.use(express.json());

   const routes = [
       conversationRouter,
       userRouter
   ];
   routes.forEach(route => app.use('/', route));

   app.listen(3000, () => {
       console.log(`Server is running on ${port}`);
   });
   ```

This issue is resolved when I mount `userRouter` before `conversationRouter`. But according to [Express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#:%7E:text=Router%2Dlevel%20middleware%20works%20in%20the%20same%20way%20as%20application%2Dlevel%20middleware%2C%20except%20it%20is%20bound%20to%20an%20instance%20of%20express.Router().), it should not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you mount all routers on the `/` path. Mount each router on its own path. Also, See [Express router middleware gets called on unexpected routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69153881/express-router-middleware-gets-called-on-unexpected-routes)

`app.ts`:

```
import express from 'express';
import conversationRouter from './conversationRouter';
import userRouter from './userRouter';

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
app.use(express.json());

app.use('/api/conversation', conversationRouter);
app.use('/api/user', userRouter);

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on ${port}`);
});
```

`conversationRouter.ts`:

```
import express from 'express';

const conversationRouter = express.Router();

const validateToken = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('validateToken');
    next();
};

conversationRouter.use(validateToken);
conversationRouter.post('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendStatus(200);
});

export default conversationRouter;
```

`userRouter.ts`:

```
import express from "express";

const userRouter = express.Router();

userRouter.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  res.sendStatus(200)
});

export default userRouter;
```

Test:

```bash
$ curl -X POST http://localhost:3000/api/user/login
OK
$ curl -X POST http://localhost:3000/api/conversation
OK
```

The server logs:

```bash
Server is running on 3000
validateToken
```